# Using RxJava to fetch object, transform a containing list, and use the list

Tags: android, rx-java, rx-android

The high level problem I'm trying to solve is transforming a list of `Foo` objects contained in a fetched `FooContainer` (Observable) to a list of `FooBar` objects using RxJava.

My (confused) attempt:

```
fooContainerObservable
  .map(container -> container.getFooList())
  .flatMap(foo -> transformFooToFooBar(foo))
  .collect( /* What do I do here? Is collect the correct thing? Should I be using lift? */)
  .subscribe(fooBarList -> /* Display the list */);
```

My confusion (or at least one point of it) is the step moving the flattened list back to a list.

Note: I'm attempting to do this in an Android app.

Comment: Could you explain why you plan to use `collect`? If you want to collect all items to a List, just call `toList`.

Comment: @zsxwing because it seemed to makes sense that I was "collect"ing multiple items from the stream of events :). I wasn't aware that `toList` existed. If you answer suggesting that, I'll mark it as the solution!

Answer (score 17, accepted):

`toList` can collect all items of an Observable into a `List` and emit it. `toList` can be implemented using `collect`, but it's much easier than `collect`. For your example, it will be:

```
fooContainerObservable
  .map(container -> container.getFooList())
  .flatMap(foo -> transformFooToFooBar(foo))
  .toList()
  .subscribe(fooBarList -> /* Display the list */);
```